# Sphinx search returning random numbers instead of string attributes

Tags: php, sphinx

I have a sphinx index, defined as follows:

```
sql_query= \
SELECT \
s.`id`, s.`name`, s.`views`, s.`released`,s.`seo_url`,\
CAST(s.`is_popular` AS SIGNED) as is_popular \
FROM `shows` s \
WHERE s.alias_id IS NULL

sql_attr_uint       = views
sql_attr_uint       = is_popular
sql_field_string    = name
sql_attr_string     = released
sql_field_string    = seo_url
```

I am querying with the php pecl extension.

The problem is that the string attributes are returned as some kind of random integers. E.g.

```
[18] => Array
(
        [id] => 3623
                [weight] => 1624
                [attrs] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 865774050003
                        [views] => 16
                        [released] => 865774050021
                        [seo_url] => 865774050029
                        [is_popular] => 0
                    )

            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3820
                [weight] => 1624
                [attrs] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 865774050059
                        [views] => 303
                        [released] => 865774050087
                        [seo_url] => 865774050095
                        [is_popular] => 0
                    )

            )
```

The non string attributes are correct, but the strings have different values at each run.

Right now i am using sql_field_string, but i tried only sql_attr_string, with the same results.

I'am using the latest sphinx version, on windows. (i also tested with 2.1 to no avail).

I'am pretty lost, anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This almost certainly means used your version of `sphinxapi.php` is too old.

You could be using the one from the server version you using - so if you've downloaded and installed a certain version of sphinx server, copy the sphinxapi.php file from the installation archive into your application folder.

(basically you have a sphinxapi.php that doesnt understand string attributes)

Comment: well, i'm not using a third party php client, but this one http://php.net/manual/en/book.sphinx.php the pecl extension. So i don't think i have a sphinxapi.php

Comment: Actully you ARE using a third party client. That is an unofficial extension, with it its own maintainers. They probably havent kept it updated to cope with string attributes. sphinxapi.php is the official client privided by sphinx developers.

Answer (score 0):

OK so the answer is that the php_sphinx.dll i'am using is probably built/compiled for an old version of sphinx that doesn't support string attributes. 
Upon switching to the provided sphinxapi.php everything works as advertised. 
thanks @barryhunter for hinting me the versioning issue.